# Box shadow using CSS

Tags: css, html-table

I am trying to create a table like the following image:

[image: Sample Table]

I have also created table like the above except the style as it is above. my table.

[image: My Table]

This is what is my CSS:

```
.table thead th {
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: thin;
    border-top: thick;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    width:300px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px grey;
    border-bottom : thin;
    border-top:thick;
}
.table th {
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px grey;
    border-bottom: thin; 
    border-top:thick;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #DDD

}
.table th,.table td {
    height: 20px;
    max-width: 250px;
    padding: 1px 5px 2px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #DDD
}
```

The result is not what I am looking for. I am not able to give you the html table code since it is generated during run time using backgrid.js with backbone.marionette.js

**UPDATE :**

```
this is the CSS



box-shadow: 
        inset 0px 11px 8px -10px #CCC,
        inset 0px -11px 8px -10px #CCC;
```

but still the line is visible between td, I want to show only the horizontal lines not the vertical one.

How to do that?

Please help me to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

Add before the table the following element:

```
<div id="fade"></div>
```

And in the CSS file:

```
#fade {
height: 22px;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,255)), color-stop(50%,rgba(247,247,247,247)), color-stop(51%,rgba(245,245,245,245)), color-stop(100%,rgba(243,243,243,243)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,255) 0%,rgba(247,247,247,247) 50%,rgba(245,245,245,245) 51%,rgba(243,243,243,243) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,255) 0%,rgba(247,247,247,247) 50%,rgba(245,245,245,245) 51%,rgba(243,243,243,243) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,255) 0%,rgba(247,247,247,247) 50%,rgba(245,245,245,245) 51%,rgba(243,243,243,243) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient( StartColorStr='#00ffffff', EndColorStr='#00f3f3f3', GradientType=1);
}
```

(change to the colors you want etc)

Comment: Yes, I got it. Updated the question with answer but i am not able to remove the line between td.

Comment: You have `border: 1px solid #DDD` when you don't need a border... try: `border-collapse:collapse`